# I always forget log rules in calculus, any way to learn the derivation?

Tags: calculus, integration, number-theory, derivatives, logarithms

In algorithms, log factors come up a lot. I always forget what to do whether you derivate or integrate, when log x becomes 1/x and so on.

What's the derivation of this rule so I can never forget what to do when encountering logs in derivates or integrals?

Comment: No matter how you choose to derive it, memorizing is always quicker.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$, then you can do implicit differentiation.

\begin{align}
y &= \log x\\
e^y &= x\\
\frac{d}{dx} e^y &= 1\\
e^y \frac{dy}{dx} &= 1\\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{1}{e^y} = \frac{1}{x}.
\end{align}

---

The indefinite integral $\int \log x \mathop{dx} = x \log x - x$ can be derived using integration by parts, or (if you remembered the antiderivative correctly) by checking that the derivative of $x \log x - x$ is indeed $\log x$.

Comment: I'm not familiar, can you explain that last two lines in the derivation? Was with you up until then. Where did dy come from and how / why is it being used?

Comment: @KaliMa I am applying chain rule to take the derivative of $e^y$. $$\frac{d}{dx} e^y = \frac{d e^y}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} = e^y \frac{dy}{dx}.$$ Then I divide both sides by $e^y$. To conclude, note that your original goal was to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, the derivative of $y=\log x$ with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the rule of the derivate of the inverse of a function, it is easy :

$$(f^{-1} (x))'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x)}$$

Here we have $f(x)=e^x$, so we have

$$\ln(x)'=\frac{1}{e^{\ln(x)}}=\frac{1}{x}$$